# Is it possible to create a table with table name as GUID

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, guid

is is possible to do

```
DECLARE @guid uniqueidentifier = NEWID();
select @guid

CREATE TABLE @guid
(
    [UserId] uniqueidentifier NOT NULL DEFAULT NewID(),
    [FirstName] nvarchar(30),
    [LastName] nvarchar(30),
    [Email] nvarchar(50)
)
```

I am just trying this concept, if it works in will use it in my web application

the above code does not work

Comment: What would be the benefit of a table with a random name?

Comment: thats hard to explain, but i will create each table for a particular user record that table name inside the table user for reference

Comment: That sounds like a horrible database design

Comment: They didn't ask if it was good design, they asked if it was possible to do what they want to do.

Comment: What error message do you get when you run the query that doesn't work?

Comment: @gowner it's always worth trying to educate newbies on better design practices.

Comment: i am open to suggestion, @DaleK, thanks a lot for your gesture, i initially thought that adding in different tables will save run during loading of data from DB to the application thats why i thought this

Comment: SQL is primarily intended to have static schema, not one that changes on the fly. And normally one has a user table with a row per user, and any other tables that are relevant to a user have a user id column with a foreign key to the user table.

Comment: I don't get why you would ever want to do this. It sounds like you need just one table, with another Guid column to identify the bulk import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a dynamic table name directly, but you can first build the SQL in a string variable and execute that; the technique is known dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @guid uniqueidentifier = NEWID();
DECLARE @strSql nvarchar(max)= N'CREATE TABLE ['+cast(@guid as nvarchar(50))+']
(
    [UserId] uniqueidentifier NOT NULL DEFAULT NewID(),
    [FirstName] nvarchar(30),
    [LastName] nvarchar(30),
    [Email] nvarchar(50)
)'
select @guid
exec sp_executesql @strSql;
```

I have added square brackets around the table name because the default representation of a guid has hyphens in it.

If the source of the table name is not a GUID (i.e. it has the potential to contain special characters, user supplied, etc)  it is good practice to clean it before using. You can use QUOTENAME() for that purpose:

```
... + quotename(cast(@guid as nvarchar(50))) + ...
```

Comment: Much safer to use `QUOTENAME()` than manually typing `[` and `]`.

Comment: Agreed, it safer to use that function if the name comes from unreliable sources. It doesn't make any difference in this example.

Comment: Consistency and setting good examples > “it’s okay this time.”

Comment: @tinazmu - counterpoint: you don't have to jump through any additional hoops here to do it with `quotename()`. So what did you save (aside from nine characters)?

Comment: @BenThul, I am against doing things without a reason, and in this case, there is no risk (would you wear a hat indoors because it is good practice?)

Comment: Would you show a kid how to drink from a bleach bottle only in the case where _you_ know the bottle has been thoroughly cleaned and filled with orange juice? Or that it's cool to not wear a seatbelt when you're just driving to the corner? In other words, why promote practices that can be bad sometimes, instead of practices that are safer _always_?

Comment: Meanwhile, you assign an `nvarchar` variable without denoting the string with an `N` prefix, another thing that might not break _here_, but could break in other scenarios when people "learn" from your code.

Comment: It's nice to add a disclaimer _after_ the code that says "if you have a vulnerability, you can do this instead" ... but still, why not just do the safer thing _all the time_? Readers won't necessarily _know_ they might need to "clean" the input, and I don't know why you would ever suggest a method that _can_ break. The "reason" you're looking for is that teaching people "best practices" is way better than teaching them "practices that are okay most of the time."